# LINQPad - Can't insert records with TIMESTAMP fields in MariaDB using MySQL (Pomelo) Provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mariadb, linqpad

I'm having this issue using the MySQL (Pomelo) provider (latest version but tried older ones as well).
I'm using 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2 as a database, and created a test table with only 3 fields:

Testtabel

- ID (INT - autogenerated)
- created_date_time (DATETIME)
- created_timestamp (TIMESTAMP)

and just execute the following code:

```
Testtabel.Add(new Testtabel(){
    CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
    CreatedTimestamp = DateTime.Now
});
SaveChanges();
```

Sadly, the result is not what I would expect, as the created_timestamp field is empty:

[image]

I've tested adding the data using the same MySqlConnector library that Pomelo is using and everything seems to be working fine:

```
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Database=xxxx");
connection.Open();

using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testtabel_sync (created_date_time, created_timestamp) VALUES (@dt, @ts)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ts", DateTime.Now);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}

using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM testtabel_sync;", connection);
using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Dump();
```

With the result (last line):

[image]

Could anyone try if they have the same problem? Is there something wrong with how I'm expecting this to work?

Comment: Perhaps `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() doesn't seem to exist. There is UnixEpoch, which is a DateTime of 1970-01-01, but that doesn't help. I could try to calculate the Unix Timestamp value myself in seconds, but that will not solve the issue as LINQPad has mapped the "CreatedTimestamp" field to a DateTime, so I cannot enter a Unix Timestamp without converting it to a DateTime again.
In the second example that does work (without using the included EF mapping in LINQPad), if I replace DateTime.Now with DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() it actually results as 0000-00-00 in the DB.

Comment: Sounds like Pomelo is getting in the way?

Comment: Just using Pomelo and creating the SQL script myself is working perfectly (see the second example in the question). It seems like there is something between LINQPad and EF that is going wrong but I have no idea where to start looking.